# How to send Firebase Notifications with URIs to implement deep linking?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

tr;dr

Just realized that this question only applies to Android because iOS handles notification a bit differently and you can do what you want with your notification.

With my understanding now I can simplify my question to the following:

> How to make an Android device display a notification with a deep link configured from a URI without coding at all?

---

We need to show notifications with deep links on the system tray of Android and iOS platforms, each notification has to open a specific screen of the apps.

The deep link has to be configured using URIs.

---

On Android, when the app is in the foreground the message from Firebase has to be handled manually. This way we are able to read all the data from the remote message and build a notification with a deep link configured using the URI.

But when the app is in the background the notification is displayed automatically by Firebase. It's not possible to configure a deep link on it.

---

We know it's possible to send data messages instead of notification messages. This would be a solution on Android because every message has to be handled manually making it possible to build the notification as we please with URI, deep links, and everything.

But this won't work on iOS. On iOS it is mandatory to send notifications messages.

---

This is the basic JSON that Firebase accepts:

```
{
  "message": {
    "notification": {
      "title": "Lorem",
      "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
    },
    "token": "..."
  }
}
```

We tried setting several combinations of `message.uri`, `message.link`, `message.action`, `message.click`, `message.click_action` but none of them worked.

We also tried with `data.uri`, `data.link`, `data.action`, `data.click`, `data.click_action` but again we had no luck.

Reading the Firebase source code ([NotificationsParams:212](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-messaging/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/messaging/NotificationParams.java#L212)) we found that there is a way to configure a link on the notification, but we didn't find anything about it on the docs.

Where and how can we specify the URI so that the notification is automatically built using it and also available when the app is in the foreground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that sending `gcm.n.link` in the `data` object works.

With the following json, Firebase Messaging 20.2.4 will automatically build a notification with the value of `gcm.n.link` in its data:

```
{
  "message": {
    "notification": {
      "title": "Lorem",
      "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
    },
    "data": {
      "gcm.n.link": "app://details/identifier"
    },
    "token": "..."
  }
}
```

Configuring an Intent Filter that matches that URI on an Activity will make Android open that Activity when the notification is tapped.

I haven't found anything related to it in the docs, found this going through their source code. So not sure if `gcm.n.link` it's supposed to be used or what but, it works so I'm happy.

If someone knows something about this please comment.